# Python IDLE: Change Python Version

Tags: python, editor, version, python-idle

I have Python 2.x and 3.x on my machine (Mac OS X 10.6). 
For some things I want to use ver 2, but for others I want ver 3. I like the IDLE software for editing/running, but it always uses version 3.

**Is there any way to change the version of the interpreter that IDLE uses?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are different versions of IDLE installed for each Python version.  Depending on how you installed Python on Mac OS X, you may find different folders in `/Applications`.  Look for a Python 3.n (n = 1 or 2) folder with an IDLE in it.  Or, from a terminal command line, you may find an `idle2.6` and an `idle3` or `idle3.1` or `idle3.2`.

Comment: Got it with Terminal. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Usually each Python version installs its own version of IDLE. I don't know how this works on Mac, but for Windows it works like this:

```
python2.7 C:\Program Files\Python27\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw
```

starts the Python 2 IDLE and

```
python3.2 C:\Program Files\Python32\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw
```

starts the Python 3 IDLE.

Answer (score 3):

In the Windows environment, if you want to use particular install of IDLE, I find the easiest way is to right click on the `.py` file and choose "open with". Then navigate to the `IDLE.bat` file in the Python version install location you want to use. I find picking just the `ilde.py` doesn't work but the `.bat` file does.

E. g.

`D:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.4\Lib\idlelib\idle.bat`

or

```
D:\Python27Desktop\ArcGIS10.4\Lib\idlelib\idle.bat
```

Comment: Thanks, I created a shortcut on the desktop for it. Really nice.

Answer (score 2):

If there are 2 or more Python versions installed on you computer but you can only open one Python IDLE (suppose IDLE using Python 2.7) and if you dont have IDLE for Python 3.5 installed on your computer (check the folder `/usr/bin` for `idle` or `idle-python2.7` And if `idle-python3.5` is not there then its not currently installed). Then you just have to install `idle-python3.5` by executing following command through CLI.

```
sudo apt install idle-python3.5
```

Or you can just install it by Software Manager in Linux.
Search for IDLE and select your preferred IDLE to install.

Answer (score 0):

In RHEL 7 after installing yum install python-tools
typing "idle3.6" worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I use Sublime 3 as my editor on mac.  Several backend files required changes.  Changes were made to  Python3.sublime-build file:

```
{
"cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/python3", "-u", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.python",
"encoding": "utf8",
"path": "/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/"
}
```

The SublimeREPL package was also installed.

The Main.sublime-menu file was edited to reflect the following:

```
{"command": "repl_open",
 "caption": "Python3 - RUN current file",
 "id": "repl_python_run",
  "mnemonic": "d",
  "args": {
        "type": "subprocess",
        "encoding": "utf8",
        "cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file_basename"],
        "cwd": "$file_path",
        "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
        "external_id": "python",
        "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
        }
}
```

These are the major changes in a nutshell.  More details with guided step-by-step instructions are available at 
 [Setting Up Sublime Text 3 for Python3 Development](http://www.jasred.com/2014/05/12/setting-up-sublime-text-3-for-python3-development/).