# Can't open "edit with idle" for python 3.4 with python 2.7 and 3.4 installed. Can only open idle manually

Tags: python, python-idle

I currently have python 2.7.6 and 3.4.0 installed. Whenever I rightclick and open with idle, and I try to run it in idle, the version used in 2.7.6. However, I need it to run in 3.4.0. I can work around this issue by opening idle manually and opening a file from idle itself, but this is pretty tedious and I'm wondering if anyone knows a solution to this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python IDLE: Change Python Version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776359/python-idle-change-python-version)

Comment: Have you tried changing the order of your Python versions in your PATH variable?

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify OS; I suspect Windows and am answering from a Windows 7 perspective.  Most entries in the right click menu corresponds to a command line, with the file name substituted for a wildcard placeholder.  (Exceptions include `cut` and `copy'.)  Some entries are present for all files.  Some, such as this one, are specific to a type of file as indicated by the extension. The right-click menu is governed by the Windows registry.

When multiple versions of Python are installed, one is designated as the default version.  If I wanted to change the designation (to 3.4, for instance), I would either go to Control Panel, Programs and Features and 'change' the Python 3.4 installation, or just re-install it from the installer.

If you do not want to do that, you can 'Edit with Idle' (2.7) and the file will then appear under File -> Recent Files on the 3.4 menu.

I have considered requesting that there be an "Edit with Idle x.y' entry for each Python version installed.  I do not know if there are techical reasons preventing that.