# too many pythons on linux

Tags: python-2.7, xubuntu

i recently started using python with xubuntu on virtualbox but i'm having problems. I want to be able to use numpy so i thought that apt-get install python-numpy would solve everything, but using the shell i kept getting `No module named numpy`. I used `IDLE` and it could find it. I also have `IDLE (using Python-2.7)`, and again it could import numpy. Then i noticed that the shell had `python 2.7.9`, while the IDLEs had `python 2.7.6`.
Using

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

this if what i get from 2.7.9 (shell)

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-17.0-py2.7.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Pillow-2.3.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock-1.0.1-py2.7.egg
/usr/local/lib/python27.zip
/usr/local/lib/python2.7
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

and from 2.7.6 (IDLE)

```
/home/alessandro
/usr/bin
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client
```

I understand that i have two versions of python installed and somehow i ended up installing packageg into only one of them (the 2.7.6).
I'd like to be able to use 2.7.9 both in the shell and in IDLE and also i'd like to install so that python 2.7.9 can see them.
I read that i can add paths to the python sys.path, but isn't there a more efficient/persistent way to do what i want?

PS: tell me if you need more informations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my projects I usually create a virtualenv for each python version I need for the project at hand. I manage them using pip to install specific versions that I need. Moreover you should be able to choose the python path in your IDE. While I'm not using IDLE, I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776359/python-idle-change-python-version) that apparently idle comes along with the python versions during install. So maybe your idle versions collide with each other. If you want to have only one python version at the time on your machine you might consider a simple remove and fresh install of your desired version. Again I would recommend pip over apt-get  etc. Hope this is of help for you.

Comment: I read just now something about virtualenv and it seems really interesting, so i'll try it for sure. Really a good suggestion. I'll try to use pip over apt-get when i can.

Answer (score 0):

Worth to check PyDev, a plugin for Eclipse to work on python.
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/pydev-python-ide-eclipse , or http://pydev.org/.
This allows you to configure the python version for different project's.
I have some project's with python 2.7 and others with 3.4.
it's checks the whole system in search for the PYTHONPATH to use!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i'll be sure to check that!

Comment: And there is pycharm ;) comes directly with github support etc.

Comment: I have pycharm, meaning i don't know how to properly use it... I'll try to find out more about its features!