# How can I change default python shell version?

Tags: python-3.x

I am using Windows 10, and I have python 2.7 and 3.6 installed. I want to open a .py file in IDLE 3.6, but when I try to open it, it opens in 2.7. How can I change the default?

Comment: Made the question legible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the python-2x or python-3x as default python IDLE, you need to change the environment variable, if you define the path for n versions of python, you will be able to use that particular version by typing that version in cmd.

See the superuser answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-to-add-python-to-the-windows-path) for step by step instruction

Answer (score 0):

There are different versions of IDLE installed for each Python version. Depending on how you installed Python on Mac OS X, you may find different folders in /Applications. Look for a Python 3.n (n = 1 or 2) folder with an IDLE in it. Or, from a terminal command line, you may find an idle2.6 and an idle3 or idle3.1 or idle3.2.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4776403/3900156

Comment: I see i know the which shell in my computer. My asking is how I can make 3.6 shell as defauly shell