# how to fix Python Error, In description is the code and the error

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, scikit-learn, libsvm

How to fix the error in the code, I'm using python 3.7, macOS high sierra
installed libraries are: `sklearn` `matplotlib` `numpy`.

**code:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm
import numpy


digits=datasets.load_digits()
'''
print(digits.data)
print(digits.target)
print(digits.images[0])
 '''

clf=svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=1.0)

print(len(digits.data))

x,y = digits.data[:-1],digits.target[:-1]
clf.fit(x,y)

print('prediction:',clf.predict(digits.data[-1]))
plt.imshow(digits.images[-1], cmap=plt.cm.gray_r, 
interpolation="nearest")
plt.show()
```

**Error:**

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/harmanthind/Documents/Python/scikit learn 
  liberary/pehla.py", line 21, in <module>
  print('prediction:',clf.predict(digits.data[-1]))

  File"/Library/Frameworks/ 
   Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site- 
    packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 548, in predict
  y = super(BaseSVC, self).predict(X)
    File 
 "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site- 
  packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 308, in predict
   X = self._validate_for_predict(X)
   File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 439, in _validate_for_predict
 X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr', dtype=np.float64, order="C")
 File 
 "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site- 
 packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 441, in check_array
 "if it contains a single sample.".format(array))
 ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
 array=[ 0.  0. 10. 14.  8.  1.  0.  0.  0.  2. 16. 14.  6.  1.  0.  0.  
 0.  0.
  15. 15.  8. 15.  0.  0.  0.  0.  5. 16. 16. 10.  0.  0.  0.  0. 12. 
  15.
  15. 12.  0.  0.  0.  4. 16.  6.  4. 16.  6.  0.  0.  8. 16. 10.  8. 
  16.
  8.  0.  0.  1.  8. 12. 14. 12.  1.  0.].
  Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has 
   a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single 
   sample.
```

Comment: The code, as posted, appears to have indentation that is messed up. Did you simply copy-paste from elsewhere?...

Comment: I copied it from my idle where it is properly indented, i was asked to give space before code lines while uploading this question here. So i did but while doing so  i didn't spaced all lines equally. So it appears not intended properly here but in my IDLE it is properly intended.

Comment: You should've corrected that. Everyone seems to think your code issues are indentation problems. Adding space before code is simply to make sure it formats properly on the site (4 spaces minimum).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you ***indented correctly*** ?

I have runned your code on my machine (*Windows 8.1*) with proper indentation and it worked *fine*.

Indented code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm
import numpy


digits=datasets.load_digits()
'''
 print(digits.data)
 print(digits.target)
 print(digits.images[0])
 '''

clf=svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=1.0)

print(len(digits.data))

x,y = digits.data[:-1],digits.target[:-1]
clf.fit(x,y)

print('prediction:',clf.predict([digits.data[-1]]))
plt.imshow(digits.images[-1], cmap=plt.cm.gray_r, interpolation="nearest")
plt.show()
```

*Furthermore, if it doesn't work, then try changing the kernel/interpreter. Try **Python 3.6.x** kernel/interpreter.*

p.s: I have used Python 3.6.0 on Thonny IDE to run test this code and it worked fine on my machine.

Comment: Yes it is intended correctly.
I copied it from my idle where it is properly indented, i was asked to give space before code lines while uploading this question here. So i did but while doing so i didn't spaced all lines equally. So it appears not intended properly here but in my IDLE it is properly intended.

How to change kernel/interpreter in python regular IDLE?

Comment: @HarmanThind Normally, each python version come with it's own IDLE. Please see this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/4776384/6390175 for more details.

Comment: @HarmanThind I am using Thonny IDE for Python and in it, you can change your interpreter via Tools -> Options -> Interpreter.

Comment: @HarmanThind I ran above code on Python 3.7.0 to test it. And it worked fine. It's working fine with Python 3.6 as well.

Comment: @HarmanThind Please check the code now, I have made a minor fix. It should be able to work well now.

Comment: It worked finally:
    print('prediction:',clf.predict([digits.data[-2]]))
i can't believe the missing brackets were causing error

Comment: Thank you so much for the help

Comment: @HarmanThind Glad I can help :') You may accept the answer by approving it though so others may kind it helpful also. :')