# How to change Linux terminal idle default version

Tags: python, terminal, python-idle

Please I installed Idle3. But when I launched it by typing `Idle` from the terminal, it loaded `python3.6.6` by default. If I search Idle under `applications`
There are three options:

1. Idle
2. Idle using python 3.6.6
3. Idle using python 3.7.0

My question is: Is it possible to change the default idle that opens when I type `Idle` from terminal?

Thank you

Comment: How....  I changed the python default version from 2.7.1 to 3.7.0 using the "update alternative" command.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a possible duplicate of [Python IDLE:Change Python Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776359/python-idle-change-python-version)`

But in any case. Here's what you can do:
In your terminal type

```
sudo nano /usr/bin/idle-python3.6.6
```

The first line should look something like this

```
/usr/bin/python3.6.6
```

Change the end of the line to the version you are looking for idle to open by defauly (3.7.0 in your case).

Hope that helps:) oh and welcome to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

If you do:

```
which idle
```

You get the path which is used for running idle, e.g. /usr/bin/idle

I'm guessing a bit but I think that it might be a soft link that points to the 3.6.6 version of idle. If so, you can see where the soft link points by doing

```
ls -l /usr/bin/idle
```

That would return something like "/usr/bin/idle -> /usr/bin/idle3.6.6"
To update the soft link, use ln with -f:

```
ln -s -f /usr/bin/idle3.7.0 /usr/bin/idle
```

And that should hopefully update the link to use the later version. Do note that I have assumed the /usr/bin path for the executables, it might be different in your case.